# Average Value Calculation

Tags: tcl

How to calculate the average value of a particular column in a text file with the help of Tcl Script ?

For example I have a text file containing 3 columns like:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

5 9 7

3 2 8
```

And I want to do the average value calculation for Column 1 only; then How can I do it using Tcl script ?

Comment: Hint: `split(" ")[0]`

Comment: You may use something like [this](https://ideone.com/Kwqdu1) if you want to use Tcl.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split by spaces to get the first column values
2. Create an empty list to store the values
3. Divide the sum by its length

someFile:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

5 9 7

3 2 8
```

**Hence**:

```
values = []             # an empty list
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]  # to remove empty lines

    for line in content:
         values.append(int(line.split(" ")[0])) # convert str to int and append

    print(sum(values) / float(len(values)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
3.25
```